# How do you properly add a 2nd pinpad to the ChipDNA Server Configuration File?

Tags: configuration, credit-card

I have ChipDNA Server fully set up and running, and it is able to communicate to my virtual PinPad which is on a different computer of the same network. Here is the example config file that is WORKING:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ChipDnaServer version="1.0.0">
<MachineName>localhost</MachineName>
<ApplicationIdentifier>CBXTEST</ApplicationIdentifier>
<Socket>192.168.1.164:1869</Socket>
<Terminals>
    <Terminal>
        <TerminalId>99961609</TerminalId>
        <TransactionKey>0gmKTUTZdwQDT5AV</TransactionKey>
        <PaymentDevices>
            <PaymentDevice>        
                <Model>Creditcall-Virtual-Attended</Model>
                <Id>29252553</Id>
                <Protocol>TCPIP</Protocol>
                <Port>1870</Port>
                <Address>192.168.1.250</Address>
                <Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
                <Parity>none</Parity>
                <Stopbits>1</Stopbits>
                <Databits>8</Databits>
                <StandbyMessage>Welcome to CBX Jose!</StandbyMessage>
            </PaymentDevice>
        </PaymentDevices>
    </Terminal>
</Terminals>
<Tms>
    <Servers>
        <Server>
            <Url>https://testtms.cardeasexml.com</Url>
            <Timeout>45000</Timeout>
        </Server>
    </Servers>
</Tms>
```

Now, I try to add a second pinpad simply by adding another . However I receive the error code "DuplicatePaymentDevice":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ChipDnaServer version="1.0.0">
<MachineName>localhost</MachineName>
<ApplicationIdentifier>CBXTEST</ApplicationIdentifier>
<Socket>192.168.1.164:1869</Socket>
<Terminals>
    <Terminal>
        <TerminalId>99961609</TerminalId>
        <TransactionKey>0gmKTUTZdwQDT5AV</TransactionKey>
        <PaymentDevices>
            <PaymentDevice>        
                <Model>Creditcall-Virtual-Attended</Model>
                <Id>29252553</Id>
                <Protocol>TCPIP</Protocol>
                <Port>1870</Port>
                <Address>192.168.1.250</Address>
                <Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
                <Parity>none</Parity>
                <Stopbits>1</Stopbits>
                <Databits>8</Databits>
                <StandbyMessage>Welcome to CBX Jose!</StandbyMessage>
            </PaymentDevice>
            <PaymentDevice>        
                <Model>Creditcall-Virtual-Attended</Model>
                <Id>29252555</Id>
                <Protocol>TCPIP</Protocol>
                <Port>1870</Port>
                <Address>192.168.1.267</Address>
                <Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
                <Parity>none</Parity>
                <Stopbits>1</Stopbits>
                <Databits>8</Databits>
                <StandbyMessage>Welcome to CBX Jose!</StandbyMessage>
            </PaymentDevice>
        </PaymentDevices>
    </Terminal>
</Terminals>
<Tms>
    <Servers>
        <Server>
            <Url>https://testtms.cardeasexml.com</Url>
            <Timeout>45000</Timeout>
        </Server>
    </Servers>
</Tms>
```

I have looked through a lot of CreditCall Documentation, and there are no example of 'multiple devices', they just say 'ChipDNA Server is capable of controlling multiple devices'. As you can see the ID is different than the previous as well as the IPAddress, but I still receive the error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the CreditCall SDK which includes ChipDNA Server is not as popular on StackOverFlow at the moment. However I have talked to CreditCall Support and got my answer in case anyone else needs this informaiton in the future:

Each standalone PinPad on a ChipDNA Server requires their own TERMINAL ID to perform separate transactions. At the time I asked this quesiton we were only assigned one Terminal ID, therefore my .config file would fail to work. CreditCall then set us up with two additional Terminals, we simply had to add each terminal to the config as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ChipDnaServer version="1.0.0">
<MachineName>localhost</MachineName>
<ApplicationIdentifier>CBXTEST</ApplicationIdentifier>
<Socket>192.168.1.164:1869</Socket>
<Terminals>
    <Terminal>
        <TerminalId>****1649</TerminalId>
        <TransactionKey>paTKZJ5kTtEArt3X</TransactionKey>
        <PaymentDevices>
            <PaymentDevice>        
                <Model>Creditcall-Virtual-Attended</Model>
                <Id>29252553</Id>
                <Protocol>TCPIP</Protocol>
                <Port>1870</Port>
                <Address>192.168.1.167</Address>
                <!--<Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
                <Parity>none</Parity>
                <Stopbits>1</Stopbits>
                <Databits>8</Databits>-->
                <StandbyMessage>Welcome to CBX Alfonso!</StandbyMessage>
                <DeviceActive>true</DeviceActive>
            </PaymentDevice>
        </PaymentDevices>
    </Terminal>
    <Terminal>
        <TerminalId>****1648</TerminalId>
        <TransactionKey>muZAAAAARvtn33DXk</TransactionKey>
        <PaymentDevices>
            <PaymentDevice>        
                <Model>Creditcall-Virtual-Attended</Model>
                <Id>29252555</Id>
                <Protocol>TCPIP</Protocol>
                <Port>1870</Port>
                <Address>192.168.1.164</Address>
                <!--<Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
                <Parity>none</Parity>
                <Stopbits>1</Stopbits>
                <Databits>8</Databits>-->
                <StandbyMessage>Welcome to CBX ServIOT!</StandbyMessage>
                <DeviceActive>true</DeviceActive>
            </PaymentDevice>
        </PaymentDevices>
    </Terminal>
    <Terminal>
        <TerminalId>****1609</TerminalId>
        <TransactionKey>0gmAAAAAdwQDT5AV</TransactionKey>
        <PaymentDevices>
            <PaymentDevice>        
                <Model>Creditcall-Virtual-Attended</Model>
                <Id>29252554</Id>
                <Protocol>TCPIP</Protocol>
                <Port>1870</Port>
                <Address>192.168.1.250</Address>
                <!--<Baudrate>9600</Baudrate>
                <Parity>none</Parity>
                <Stopbits>1</Stopbits>
                <Databits>8</Databits>-->
                <StandbyMessage>Welcome to CBX Jose!</StandbyMessage>
                <DeviceActive>true</DeviceActive>
            </PaymentDevice>
        </PaymentDevices>
    </Terminal>
</Terminals>
<Tms>
    <Servers>
        <Server>
            <Url>https://testtms.cardeasexml.com</Url>
            <Timeout>45000</Timeout>
        </Server>
    </Servers>
</Tms>
```

This configuration has all 3 pinpads, located on separate computers within the same network to communicate with ChipDNA Server.